# How many graphs on [$n$] vertices are isomorphic to $K_n$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

Total Number of Graphs on a vertex set $[n]$ = $2^{\binom{n}{2}}$
Since the total number of isomorphisms is equivalent to total number of bijection $\implies$ $n!$

What it would tell if divide these two $\frac{2^{\binom{n}{2}}}{n!}$, Maybe the lower bound for no of isomorphisms?

Is there any way to find a closed form for this?

Comment: Your title is a completely different question from the body of your text.

Comment: Perhaps, thats mostly what I have attempted to solve it. I am trying to count numbers of graphs isomorphic to $K_n$ for a given vertex set |V| = n

Comment: How many have you found when $n=3$ or $n=4$?

Comment: well I don't get any integer for solving the fraction I have given. Its  4/3 in both cases

Comment: I suggested a small value so that you can actually try thinking about what they are, rather than hoping for the best with a guess at a formula.

Comment: for n=3 there is $C_3$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither $2^{\binom n2}$ nor $n!$ are relevant.

If a graph with vertex set $[n]$ is isomorphic to $K_n$, then in particular it must have every edge $ij$ for $i,j \in [n]$ (well, with $i\ne j$). That **completely determines the edge set**. Since we know there is only one possible edge set, there is **only one** possible graph. That completely answers your question.

---

In principle, you could do a roundabout calculation. For any $n$-vertex graph $H$:

- There are $n!$ possible bijections between $[n]$ and $V(H)$. Therefore the graphs on vertex set $[n]$ isomorphic to $H$ have, altogether, $n!$ different isomorphisms to $H$.
- However, that doesn't mean there's $n!$ such graphs, because each of them might have multiple isomorphisms to $H$. There's a word for that number. $\text{Aut}(H)$ is the automorphism group of $H$, and $|\text{Aut}(H)|$ is its size: the number of isomorphisms from $H$ to itself. A graph isomorphic to $H$ has $|\text{Aut}(H)|$ different isomorphisms to $H$.
- So there must be $\frac{n!}{|\text{Aut}(H)}$ graphs on vertex set $[n]$ isomorphic to $H$.

In the case of $K_n$, the automorphism group contains all $n!$ possible permutations of $[n]$, so $|\text{Aut}(H)| = n!$. This also tells us that there is only $\frac{n!}{n!} = 1$ graph with vertex set $[n]$ isomorphic to $K_n$.

---

The calculation $2^{\binom n2}/n!$ tells us something completely different.

From the above, we see that for each $n$-vertex graph $H$, there are at most $n!$ graphs with vertex set $[n]$ isomorphic to $H$ (because there's $n!/a$ of them for some $a \ge 1$). There are also $2^{\binom n2}$ possible graphs with vertex set $[n]$. If we gather them up into classes of graphs isomorphic to each other (a.k.a. isomorphism classes) then there will be at least $2^{\binom n2}/n!$ different classes.

(In fact there will be more. $2^{\binom n2}/n!$ is what we'd get if each class had $n!$ elements. But many of them are smaller.)